# Angular Component with tr as container

Tags: angular, components, angular6

I have a table and I am creating angular components as rows for that table:

```
  <tbody>
    <ng-template appAddTableRows></ng-template>
  </tbody>
```

This is the Code creating the Component

```
let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(RowComponent);
let componentRef = this.flightRows.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

I edited the component selector to this: [app-row]
So now it works but I have a useless div-Container around every row. For example:

```
<div app-row="" _nghost-c19=""><tr _ngcontent-c19=""> row works</tr></div>
```

I would prefer if that container would be a tr. And I could get rid of the div. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the selector. Instead of `[app-row]` (or whatever it currently is), change it to `tr[app-row]`, and remove the `tr` tag from the template

Comment: Glad to help. If that resolves your issue, please feel free to mark the answer as accepted using the green tick icon so that others can more easily find this solution. Thanks